# C++ destructor order of member with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

If class `A` contains class `B`, then when `A` destruct, `B`'s destructor will be called first, i.e., the reversed order of their nested relationship.

But what if `A` contains a `shared_ptr` of `B`, while `B` contains a raw pointer to `A`, how should we handle the destructor to make it safe?

Considering the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

struct B;
struct A {
  int i = 1;
  std::shared_ptr<B> b;

  A() : b(std::make_shared<B>(this)) {}

  ~A() {
    b = nullptr;
    std::cout << "A destruct done" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct B {
  A *a;

  B(A *aa) : a(aa) {}

  ~B() {
    usleep(2000000);
    std::cout << "value in A: " << a->i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B destruct done" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  {
    A a;
  }
  std::cout << "done\n";
  return 0;
}
```

You can see in `A`'s destructor, I explicitly set b to `nullptr`, which will trigger `B`'s destructor immediately, and blocking until it finish.
The output will be：

```
Hello, World!
value in A: 1
B destruct done
A destruct done
done
```

but if I comment out that line

```
  ~A() {
    // b = nullptr; // <---
    std::cout << "A destruct done" << std::endl;
  }
```

The output will be:

```
Hello, World!
A destruct done
value in A: 1
B destruct done
done
```

it seems that `A`'s destructor finished without waiting `B` to destruct. But in this case, I expected segment fault, since when `A` already destructed, `B` tried to access the member of `A`, which is invalid. But why the program doesn't produce segment fault? Does it happen to be OK (i.e., `undefined behavior`)?

Also, when I change

```
 {
    A a;
 }
```

to

```
  A * a = new A();
  delete a;
```

the output is still the same, no segment fault.

Comment: Destruction happens in reverse order of construction. You should be able to follow that and work out what happens. It's a straight serial process. And btw; setting a variable to `nullptr` (or similar) frees *no* memory. And if your program contains UB, then *all* of it is invalid and *anything* is OK.

Comment: I don't even understand how the code can possibly work, or even compile, when you use an incomplete type `B`

Comment: `"A destruct done"` is somewhat misleading: it's printed **inside the dtor**, during destruction. Not after it. I see that you have reset the smart ptr before, so there is nothing significant left to do. But it's a bad idea in general to print that inside a body, before destruction of members and bases (no bases here but I make a general point).

Comment: So apparently GCC is tolerant for forward declarations as long as you provide a complete definition later. Which seems fishy to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to be precise about what is happening. When `A` is destroyed, the following events happen in the following order:

- `A::~A()` is called.
- The `A` object's lifetime ends. The object still exists, but is no longer within its lifetime. ([basic.life]/1.3)
- The body of `A::~A()` is executed.
- `A::~A()` implicitly calls the destructors of direct non-static members of `A` in reverse declaration order ([class.dtor]/9, [class.base.init]/13.3)
- `A::~A()` returns.
- The `A` object ceases to exist ([class.dtor]/16). The memory that it used to occupy becomes "allocated storage" ([basic.life]/6) until it is deallocated.

(All references are to the C++17 standard).

In the second version of the destructor:

```
~A() {
    std::cout << "A destruct done" << std::endl;
}
```

after the statement is printed, the member `b` is destroyed, which causes the owned `B` object to be destroyed. At that point, `i` has not yet been destroyed, so it is safe to access it. After that, the `B` destructor returns. Then, `i` is "destroyed" (see [CWG 2256](http://wg21.link/P1358#2256) for some subtleties). Finally, the destructor of `A` returns. At that point, it would no longer be legal to attempt to access the member `i`.

Comment: I was thinking same subject but the weird thing is when we change the declaration order, it doesn't crash and works fine. Of course it doesn't prove that it is legal but it is weird anyway.

Comment: @arnes Then it would not be legal, in light of the resolution to CWG 2256. However, in practice this will never cause a segfault because the `i` member can't be deallocated independently from the `A` object that contains it.

Comment: Yes you are right, i think your answer deserve to be accepted.

Comment: Note that in general, since the ownership is shared, the pointed `B` doesn't necessarily get destroyed because there may be other owners (though that is not the case in the simple example). In such case the access to `i` would be after `~A` has returned, and thus UB.

Answer (score 1):

B has a pointer to A, but doesn't deallocate the memory of it (e.g. no delete). So The pointer is removed but not the memory allocated, which is all fine.

Basically, the pointer is on the stack and it contains the address of some (assumed) allocated memory on the heap. Yes it get removed from the stack, but the allocated memory remains. That's what `delete` is for. To remove the allocated memory on the heap. However in your case, you don't want that memory to be removed and your pointer is what we call a non-owning pointer. It points to something, but it's not responsible about the cleanup (actually B doesn't own the memory that the pointer is pointing to).

Comment: So does it happen to be OK? (I mean, the memory of A in stack already free, but the content is still there. But if there's something else overwrite that part of memory in stack,  then it should be something undefined when B still try to access A)

Answer (score 1):

> If class A contains class B, then when A destruct, B's destructor will be called first, i.e., the reversed order of their nested relationship.

No. If you destroy an object of type `A`, that calls the destructor of `A`, so that is called first.

However, call to `B`'s destructor will finish first: The destructor of `A` begins by executing the destructor body, and then proceeds to destroy the sub objects. The destructor body finishes first, then the sub object destructors, and finally the destructor of `A` will be complete.

> But what if A contains a shared_ptr of B, while B contains a raw pointer to A, how should we handle the destructor to make it safe?

In the destructor body of `A`, make the pointed `B` point somewhere else other than the object that is being destroyed:

```
~A() {
    b->a = nullptr;
}
```

If you point it to null such as in my shown example, then you must also make sure that `B` can handle the situation that `B::a` may be null i.e. check before accessing through the pointer.

> it seems that A's destructor finished without waiting B to destruct.

That's not what we observe. The *body* of the destructor of `A` has finished, but the destructor does not finish until the member destructors finish first.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that your comment is incorrect:

```
~A() {
  std::cout << "A destruct done" << std::endl;
}
```

A destructor is *DONE* when you get out of the curly braces. You can see that in a debugger, doing step-by-step. That is where `b` will be deleted.